# How legit is this website in telling if the phone is sim unlocked

Tags: iphone, unlock

How legit is this website. It says my phone is not sim locked but I'm to scared to update it and ruin the jailbreak unlock.

Somebody said they could factory unlock my phone for free so I gave them my IMEI number now this website says its unlock. Previously my phone was unlocked via ultraSn0w.

Now I want to restore my iPhone and not use ultraSn0w to unlock it.

http://iunlocker.net/check_imei.php

Comment: I get "403 forbidden" when visiting the link or http://iunlocker.net/ directly...

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably get what you pay for, although some sites have a vested interest in choosing one answer over another. A site selling unlock services would benefit from more SIM showing as locked. A site that sells services fixing updated phones that broke (or a site run by a cell carrier with the intent to re-lock as many devices as it can) might benefit from more SIM showing as safely unlocked.

Comment: Well since it is an unlocking website it would benefit by telling me my phone is locked. It told me phone was unlocked. Plus i tried with a locked phone and it told me it was locked so it seams pretty legit for telling you if you phone is locked or unlocked

Comment: There clearly are services that have good and relatively up to date access to the carrier unlock databases, so it's not too far fetched to assume the site is giving you a correct answer. It's just you face some pain and potential cost if it's wrong.